# Execute a Stored Procedure in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, select

For an instance I a select statement and it is returning 1000 rows. I need to execute a particular stored procedure for every row the the select statement is returning.

have you got any idea how can I do that?

Comment: what server are you using? Sql Server?

Answer (score 12):

Construct the EXECUTE statements in your select like this:

```
SELECT 'EXEC sp_whatever ' + parameter stuff
FROM   your_table
```

Then run the results! Alternatively, paste your results into a spreadsheet package, and use string concatenation to construct the EXEC statements - just create a formula and paste it down the 1,000 rows. I personally prefer the first approach.

To clarify the "parameter stuff", take the example of a stored procedure that takes two `int` parameters that you want to take from columns you `your_table`. You'd then have something like this:

```
SELECT 'EXEC sp_whatever ' + CAST(field1 AS varchar) + ', ' + CAST(field2 AS varchar)
FROM    your_table
```

Not the need to be careful with string fields here - you run the risk of inadvertently exposing yourself to your own SQL injection attack, as with any SQL string concatenation.

*I am reading your "for an instance" as "this is a one-off task". If this is a task that needs automating, then one of the other answers may be the right approach.*

Comment: @Hamish - not sure what you mean? There are not many more details in the question to go on here.

Comment: @Ben - for instance, if you need to run the SP for each row, passing in the values of the Field1 and Field2 columns, assuming both ints, you'd have something like: `'EXEC sp_whatever ' + CAST(Field1 AS varchar) + ', ' + CAST(Field2 AS varchar) FROM your_table`. Then the actual command executed would be of the form `EXEC sp_whatever 123, 456`.

Comment: Was that really worth a -1 after over 4 years?

Comment: I hadn't checked the date, to be honest. But yes, it was--the answer to the exact issue I was having was incomplete to the point of being unhelpful. If that's not a down-vote, I don't know what is. Thanks for the update.

Comment: 7 people disagree with you Ben. Sorry you couldn't work it out from what's there - if you found the elaboration in my comment helpful, I'll update the answer with it.

Comment: I tried to upvote you yesterday, but it only works if you edit the post. Secondly, the fact that 7 people found your answer helpful means that 7 people on the internet who had my same issue knew more about SQL than me, which isn't particularly surprising.

Comment: "..run the results! "? How does one run the results after creating 1-N statements without having to join them in Excel?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
declare @execstatementsbatch nvarchar(max)

select @execstatementsbatch = ''

SELECT @execstatementsbatch = @execstatementsbatch   + 'EXEC UpdateQty ' + ItemCode +  ', '  + QtyBO +  '; ' 
FROM ITEMSPO 
INNER JOIN ..... 
<some conditions>

exec(@execstatementsbatch)
```

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly.*

Assuming you are on SQL Server 2005 upwards, you could create a table-valued user defined function and use the [`OUTER APPLY` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) in your query.

Comment: Yes, it surely is. It was one of the many things I was seriously excited about in 2005.

Answer (score 1):

Most RDBMS will let you select rows from stored procedure result sets. Just put your stored procedures in the FROM clause, as you would for common table expressions. For instance:

```
SELECT sp.ColumnInResultSet, t.BaseTableColumnName
FROM sp_whatever ( Args) sp INNER JOIN BaseTable t ON t.ID = sp.ID;
```

Comment: Do you know which RDBMS support this? I just tried with SQL Server 2008 and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_userwise_columns_value
(
    @userid BIGINT
)
AS 
BEGIN
        DECLARE @maincmd NVARCHAR(max);
        DECLARE @columnlist NVARCHAR(max);
        DECLARE @columnname VARCHAR(150);
        DECLARE @nickname VARCHAR(50);

        SET @maincmd = '';
        SET @columnname = '';
        SET @columnlist = '';
        SET @nickname = '';

        DECLARE CUR_COLUMNLIST CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
        FOR
            SELECT columnname , nickname
            FROM dbo.v_userwise_columns 
            WHERE userid = @userid

        OPEN CUR_COLUMNLIST
        IF @@ERROR <> 0
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK
                RETURN
            END   

        FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_COLUMNLIST
        INTO @columnname, @nickname

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @columnlist = @columnlist + @columnname + ','

                FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_COLUMNLIST
                INTO @columnname, @nickname
            END
        CLOSE CUR_COLUMNLIST
        DEALLOCATE CUR_COLUMNLIST  

        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE name = 'v_userwise_columns_value')
            BEGIN
                SET @maincmd = 'CREATE VIEW dbo.v_userwise_columns_value AS SELECT sjoid, CONVERT(BIGINT, ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @userid) + ') as userid , ' 
                            + CHAR(39) + @nickname + CHAR(39) + ' as nickname, ' 
                            + @columnlist + ' compcode FROM dbo.SJOTran '
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @maincmd = 'ALTER VIEW dbo.v_userwise_columns_value AS SELECT sjoid, CONVERT(BIGINT, ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @userid) + ') as userid , ' 
                            + CHAR(39) + @nickname + CHAR(39) + ' as nickname, ' 
                            + @columnlist + ' compcode FROM dbo.SJOTran '
            END

        --PRINT @maincmd
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @maincmd
END

-----------------------------------------------
SELECT * FROM dbo.v_userwise_columns_value
```